# Scrolling with listview and custom TextView adapter throws off ordering?

Tags: android

I have a custom adapter that I bind to a listview. That part is fine. When I scroll the listview, the ordering is thrown off because if I scroll back to the beginning (i.e scroll back up after scrolling down) the TextView shown is not the first one. Is there something I have to handle in the adapter during scrolling?

```
public class TextViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter 
{
    private Context context;

    public TextViewAdapter(Context c) 
    {
        context = c;
    }

    //---returns the number of images---
    public int getCount() {
        return textViews.size();
    }

    //---returns the ID of an item--- 
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    //---returns an TextView---
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
    {
        TextView tv;
        Log.d("Position",  Integer.toString(position));
        if (convertView == null) {

            tv = (TextView)textViews.get(position);
        } else {
            tv = (TextView) convertView;
        }            
        return tv;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You implement `getView` method in a wrong way. If you use the `convertView` you should reset its text content, like

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
{
    TextView tv;
    Log.d("Position",  Integer.toString(position));
    if (convertView == null) {

        tv = (TextView)textViews.get(position);
    } else {
        tv = (TextView) convertView;
        // HERE, set its content
        tv.setText(textViews.get(position).getText().toString());
    }            
    return tv;
}
```

A `ListView` will recycle children views for you, when it scrolls and therefore some children go invisible, thus becoming reusable. That's why every `convertView` is null at first but turns not null when the `ListView` scrolls down. But those not null `convertView`s still hold their original text content, you should manually reset their content.

By the way, you don't need to new a lot of `TextView` when the app starts, just a list of `String` is ok, like

```
/* somewhere else */
List<String> strings = ...

public class TextViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter 
{
    /* ... */

    //---returns the number of images---
    public int getCount() {
        return strings.size();
    }

    /* ... */

    //---returns an TextView---
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
    {
        TextView tv;
        Log.d("Position",  Integer.toString(position));
        if (convertView == null) {
            tv = new TextView(context);
            tv.setText(strings.get(position));
        } else {
            tv = (TextView) convertView;
            // HERE, set its content
            tv.setText(strings.get(position));
        }            
        return tv;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A major problem that you will run into is that you are trying to save a reference to the Views used by the Adapter:

```
tv = (TextView)textViews.get(position);
```

The problem is that you are competing with the recycler in Adapter and this will create *unpredictable* results... In short you cannot do this. Please watch [World of ListView](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70) by Android developers for more information.

In short, you should change your approach so your Adapter keeps a list of the Strings that the TextViews will display, not the TextViews themselves.

Answer (score 0):

if convertView is null you should re-inflator the view, otherwise you need to reset data on the convertView.

Comment: I've seen examples of inflating but it seems the inflating in happing on an xml layout file. I add TextView's dynamically at runtime. What do I pass 
inflater.inflate(R.layout.calendarcell, null);

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        cellView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.calendarcell, null);

Comment: yes, inflating is only for widgets defined in xml, if you add it dynamically, you can just new an TextView and assign it to convertView. ConvertView just means you can re-use it, but when it's null it may be the correct time for you to re-create it, either by inflator from xml or just dynamically new it.